# Rename only classes with ProGuard

Tags: java, proguard

Is it possible to rename only classes with ProGuard, and leave rest untouched?

Comment: Why do you need proguard doing this?

Comment: Can you recommend some other software that can be used to rename only classes?

Comment: I suppose, in obfuscation process, class, method and every thing will be changed into meaningless word, and if obfuscation only change class name, every reference to that changed class will be changed accordingly. It's not really make sense for your requirement.